# How to convert varchar to TRY_TO_NUMBER with decimal in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need some help in snowflake where i need to convert a varchar to number type with 2 digits as a decimal values. Below is the sample input , the query i used and the out put i want. but unfortunately my query is not working as expected.

Sample

| Column1 |
| --- |
| 000000006000 |
| 000000010000 |
| 000000000800 |
| 000000004000 |

Snowflake query:

```
Select TRY_TO_NUMBER(Column1,10,2)/100 from sampletable;
```

but the result is not expected as below.

Expected Out put :

| Column1 |
| --- |
| 60.00 |
| 100.00 |
| 8.00 |
| 40.00 |

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
Select (TRY_TO_NUMBER(Column1)/100)::DECIMAL(10,2)
FROM SampleTable;

DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
-- name type
-- (TRY_TO_NUMBER(Column1)/100)::DECIMAL(10,2)  NUMBER(10,2)
```

Comment: can you help me understand why my syntax was wrong

Comment: i tried your query it didnt shwos  .00 at decimals

Comment: @user15488631 Show vs is. Please check metadata of the column which I have already provided: `type - NUMBER(10,2)`. If you are using Snowsight you could [Increase decimal precision at data preview tab](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-data-databases-view#data-preview-tab) to display more places after decimal point